# Relative Indexed table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which has no primary key as seen below

| ID | Version | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Version 1 |
| 1 | 2 | Version 2 |
| 2 | 1 | Version 1 |
| 2 | 2 | Version 2 |
| 2 | 3 | Version 3 |
| 3 | 1 | Version 1 |

Is there a way in sql server to increment [Version] every time I repeat an existing [ID]? And if [ID] does not exist, Default to "1" without having to write queries to do so.

Basically a conditional Index.

Comment: You want to store this value, or retrieve it when you run a query? If you want to store it, I advise against it, because it will be a source of problems as the table gets larger (basically any time you update, insert, or delete a row, you have to update the whole table to keep it in sync).

Comment: Perhaps this: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Notes)` But this breaks quickly (`'Version 10' < 'Version 2'`). And again you don't want to _store_ or _index_ that, just derive it at read time so you don't have to maintain it on every single write. If you had an identity column or DateTimeCreated or something, you could use that...

Comment: "...every time I repeat an existing [ID]..." -- But in this case which one is the older one and which one is the newer one? You probably want to add a date or timestamp to the table, to find out which is which.

Comment: OK, I will just have the Version Number added via query in the background, I was just trying to see if there was a way to do it without me having to do some background work.

Answer (score 0):

Does not seem to be reasonably possible.

Better to just use `select max of [Version] +1 from <table> where [ID]=[Inputted ID]`